# CSS Boxes: float: left, but start from the left when jumping into the next line

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have got a couple of boxes containing text which should be displayed next to each other. They all have a fixed width, but a variable height (depending on their content). They are inside of a container with a variable width.

If there are too many boxes I want them to jump into the next line and start from the left again. I realized this using left floated boxes. This causes a problem if the first box per line is higher than the next one, because then the ones from the new line won't start from the left. Here's a demo:

HTML:

```
<section>
    <article>One: This ​​​​text is so long, it's so long oh my gosh!</article>
    <article>Two</article>
    <article>Three: bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla</article>
    <article>Four</article>
</section>​
```

CSS:

```
section{
    width: 300px; /* For demo, this can vary */
    overflow: hidden;
}
article{
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    background: #dddddd;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
}
​
```

You can also have a look at this JSFiddle, where you can see the problem immediately: http://jsfiddle.net/dwr6K/ Box "Three" starts right from Box "One", although I'd like it to start in the new line under Box "One". Sadly I can't use `clear: left` because I don't know how many boxes will fit in a line.

Is there a way to prevent this and to display it the way I'd like to?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. What is the case when you want the boxes to be under each other instead of floated?

Comment: I think (though I might be wrong) that you will need Javscript (or some library like jQuery) to solve this...

Comment: @Will - No, they should be floated, that's okay. But have a look at box "Three" in the demo. It's right under box "Two", but it should break into the next line so that it is under Box "One".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here: http://jsfiddle.net/dwr6K/9/

Just remove `float: left;`

and add

```
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
```

to `article`.

As @JimmyX pointed out, do go through this post about [**Cross-Browser Inline-Block**](http://blog.mozilla.org/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/)

Basically, what `float:left` does is it makes each element stick next to the leftmost div it can find. And hence if the heights vary, you don't get the desired layout.

Comment: That's it. Thank you so much for the fast and detailed answer!

Comment: You're welcome @YMMD. :)
Mr. `downvoter`, I would really like to know the reason.

Comment: Just used this to fix an issue on a project for work. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `display: inline-block` instead of `float: left` if you're not too worried about support for older browsers.

Here's a [much more detailed rundown](http://blog.mozilla.org/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/) of `display: inline-block`'s quirks.

To get your example working, simply use:

```
article {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 100px;
    background: #dddddd;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, too! abhshkdz was a bit faster. :-) Mozilla's Blog posting was very helpful!

Comment: @JimmyX the OP doesn't seem to care about older browsers support. The chosen answer of course won't work in IE

Answer (score 0):

If the heights all vary then have a look at the jQuery plugin Masonary - http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: That's what the OP doesn't want I think. (S)he wants them to start from left and not float up into vacant space.

Comment: I have to admit that I never thought about that kind of a solution. This would also be okay, but if possible I would prefer a solution which does not utilize Javascript. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a clear left on every odd div assuming you only want 2 divs to ever be paired together. See: http://jsfiddle.net/dwr6K/

That is, add the line `article:nth-child(odd) { clear: left; }`

Comment: As I said in my question there are not always two boxes inside a line. Depending on the width of their parent node, there can be more or less.